# Query two separate tables passing results within the second query while only keeping the results of the first query if the second query returns null

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

What is the best way to query a table then pass the result to another query in a different table but only keep the results from the first query if the second query returns null or is empty?

I am trying to `SELECT id, name, email FROM ACCOUNT WHERE email IN ('George@yahoo.com', 'Tom@aol.com')`
Then take the returned id's and `SELECT memberId=1 and member2Id = (the returned id) FROM FAMILY IF NULL`. If its NULL then return the data in the first query or else remove that member from the results in the first query.

What is the most efficient way to do this? Initially I was going to do the first query. Then pass the resulting id's in an array. Then iterate through the array passing the ids in the second query and if it returns not null then I will remove the id from the array. However this seems highly inefficient since I would be running two separate queries. I'm new to SQL so if there's a better way to do this I would love to learn, thanks!

Comment: How your first query is related to second query and one more thing your second query seems wrong please put your complete query as second query may like SELECT memberid1, (select member id from x) as menberid2 from family where column is null.

Comment: They are related. The first query retrieves the id of a user based off their email. The id is then used in the FAMILY table for the second query as member2Id. If the second query comes up empty then the members are unrelated.If they are unrelated (as determined by the second query) then I want that users id, name, and email (as retrieved by the first query). Does that answer your question? The queries above aren't necessarily correct, its just me trying to explain more about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes it is. So here you can use correlated queries to get desire output. Can you build your correlated query or not. Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* what you're talking about is, but you might need to expand your explanation:

```
SELECT id, name, email FROM ACCOUNT 
WHERE email IN ('George@yahoo.com', 'Tom@aol.com')
   AND id not in (select member2Id from FAMILY where memberId=1)
```

Comment: I think this is really close! Thanks I am going to play around with this. For second part it must take two parameters, that is memberId and member2Id. memberId is extracted by who is running the statement, member2Id is the id found in the first query.

Comment: You did it! You are the man, thank you so much! As soon as I get more rep I will up vote this. I have been plagued by this for far too long. My PHP solution would have been so much slower. Do you have any books or tutorials to recommend?

Comment: You're welcome, bsub. Sorry, no specific SQL tutorials to recommend - I have pretty much learned from experience. A good way to learn is to keep asking questions here :)